# Rename and recode range of new variables in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I essentially want recode and rename a range of variables in a dataframe. I am looking for a way to do this in the single step.

Example in pseudo-code:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- iris %>% head()

df %>% mutate(
   paste0("x", 1:3) = across(       # In the example I want to rename 
      Sepal.Length:Petal.Length,    # the variables I've selected
      ~ .x + 1                      # and recoded to "x1" ... "x5"
   )
)
df
```

Desired output:

```
     x1    x2    x3 Petal.Width Species
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>   <fct>
1   5.1   3.5   1.4         0.2  setosa
2   4.9   3.0   1.4         0.2  setosa
3   4.7   3.2   1.3         0.2  setosa
4   4.6   3.1   1.5         0.2  setosa
5   5.0   3.6   1.4         0.2  setosa
6   5.4   3.9   1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `rename_with()` is what you want. After that you can manipulate these renamed columns with `mutate(across(...))`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~ paste0("x", seq_along(.x)), Sepal.Length:Petal.Length) %>%
  mutate(across(x1:x3, ~ .x * 10))

  x1 x2 x3 Petal.Width Species
1 51 35 14         0.2  setosa
2 49 30 14         0.2  setosa
3 47 32 13         0.2  setosa
4 46 31 15         0.2  setosa
5 50 36 14         0.2  setosa
6 54 39 17         0.4  setosa
```

---

If you want to manipulate and rename a range of columns in one step, try the argument `.names` in `across()`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Length, ~ .x * 10,
                .names = "x{seq_along(.col)}"),
         .keep = "unused", .after = 1)

  x1 x2 x3 Petal.Width Species
1 51 35 14         0.2  setosa
2 49 30 14         0.2  setosa
3 47 32 13         0.2  setosa
4 46 31 15         0.2  setosa
5 50 36 14         0.2  setosa
6 54 39 17         0.4  setosa
```

*Hint: You can use `seq_along()` to create a sequence 1, 2, ... along with the selected columns, or `match()` to get the positions of the selected columns in the data, i.e. 
 `.names = "x{match(.col, names(df))}"`.*

Comment: I've used `rename_with()` in my current code, as a secondary step after recoding my variables. However, I was hoping there would be a way to make this a one-step process.

Comment: @PålBjartan see my update. The last part of my answer manipulate a range of columns and rename them in one step.

Comment: Thanks! The last part is what I was looking for. I was unaware of the `.names` argument in `across()` or that it is possible to add functions within quotation marks like that. `seq_along()` and `match()` is very useful indeed. I learned three new things today. =)

Comment: To elaborate on the problem: I have a dataframe with a large number survey data, with variables from that I need to recode and rename in different ways. Some must be recoded specifically, others can be recoded and renamed in a similar manner. Hence my question. I've been using the `rename_with() %>% mutate()` combo, but the sheer number of variables makes this somewhat cluttered and tedious wo write. As such, using `.names = "x{seq_along(.col)}"` will spare me considerable redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

The below code allows you to just input the column numbers into a for loop, not sure if this is what you're going for.

```
require(dplyr)

df <- iris %>% head()


for(i in 1:3){
  names(df)[i] <- paste0("x",i)
}

df
```

Outputs:

```
   x1  x2  x3 Petal.Width Species
1 5.1 3.5 1.4         0.2  setosa
2 4.9 3.0 1.4         0.2  setosa
3 4.7 3.2 1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4.6 3.1 1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5.0 3.6 1.4         0.2  setosa
6 5.4 3.9 1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: You dont need a `for` loop here or the `c()`, you can just do `names(df)[1:3] <- paste0("x",1:3)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still fairly new here! I took the `c()` out, but couldn't the for loop assist in making the modification of the input simpler? IE: having to change one set of arguments versus two?

Comment: Well welcome! There are certainly instances where loops can be useful - and to be clear what you have is not wrong - but R generally prefers vectorization when possible. I dont see how a `for` loop would benefit over vectorization in this example, but yes, loops do have some advantages.

Comment: Vectorization is more efficient than a loop in R.

Answer (score 1):

You could add consecutive numbers to `n` columns with the same prefix this way:

```
df <- iris %>% head()

n <- 3
colnames(df)[1:n] <- sprintf("x%s",1:n)
```

output:

```
# x1  x2  x3 Petal.Width Species
# 1 5.1 3.5 1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2 4.9 3.0 1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3 4.7 3.2 1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4 4.6 3.1 1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5 5.0 3.6 1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6 5.4 3.9 1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Of any nonconsecutive number of columns by:

```
n <- c(1,3,5)
colnames(df)[n] <- sprintf("x%s",n)

#   x1 Sepal.Width  x3  Petal.Width     x5
# 1 5.1         3.5 1.4         0.2 setosa
# 2 4.9         3.0 1.4         0.2 setosa
# 3 4.7         3.2 1.3         0.2 setosa
# 4 4.6         3.1 1.5         0.2 setosa
# 5 5.0         3.6 1.4         0.2 setosa
# 6 5.4         3.9 1.7         0.4 setosa
```